# Change copy, but changes parent. Why?

Tags: python

I created 2d list, then copied it and change first element of a copy with f2 function. But somehow original list changes too. But I think that created copy by value, it's not referenced to the parent. How can I change copy list and do not change original?

```
def f2(m):
    m[0][0] = 99

k = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
m = k[:][:] #[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

print(k)
f2(k)
print(m)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `m = k[:][:]` does *not* create a deep-copy of the list. It just creates a shallow copy with the first `[:]` and then creates *another* shallow copy of that shallow copy with the second `[:]`.

Try `m = [x[:] for x in k]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`k[:][:]` doesn't create a deep copy of the list `k`. That's why changing the values in `m` is changing the values in `k` as well. You can use python `deepcopy` instead :

```
from copy import deepcopy
m = deepcopy(k)
```

As mentioned in the python docs :

> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
>
> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

Read more about deepcopy and shallow copy [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)